# Is there a way to fetch table name and row count of all the tables in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Can I get table name and count of that table in BIGQUERY, because there are no columns like row_count or table_rows in GCP for information_schema to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [BigQuery's INFORMATION_SCHEMA documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro).

You can use it to query system defined views to get metadata about your BigQuery objects (including datasets, tables, etc.).

Comment: Hiii, but it only gives me metadata about the table descriptions and options, not the row count .